# Building kni library in meta-dpdk

Tags: yocto, qemu, dpdk

I want to use an application which requires kni library of `dpdk`. To build the `kni` library, it is required to provide the `kernel_dir` in `meson_options.txt`.

As I am building the linux image for qemu, I am unable to find the correct directory for the `kernel_dir`, which contains the header files for it. For instance, I provided the `kernel_dir` as:

> "/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs/lib/modules/5.15.108-yocto-standard".

This gave me error while compiling. The error it showed up is:

```
/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs/lib/modules/5.15.108-yocto-standard M=/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/build/kernel/linux/kni src=/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/kernel/linux/kni 'MODULE_CFLAGS= -include /home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/config/rte_config.h -I/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/lib/eal/include -I/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/lib/kni -I/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/build -I/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/kernel/linux/kni' modules ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE=--sysroot=/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/recipe-sysr
| FAILED: kernel/linux/kni/rte_kni.ko
| /home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs/lib/modules/5.15.108-yocto-standard M=/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/build/kernel/linux/kni src=/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/kernel/linux/kni 'MODULE_CFLAGS= -include /home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/config/rte_config.h -I/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/lib/eal/include -I/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/lib/kni -I/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/build -I/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/git/kernel/linux/kni' modules ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE=--sysroot=/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/dpdk/23.03-r0/recipe-sysr
| make: Entering directory '/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs/lib/modules/5.15.108-yocto-standard'
| make: *** No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop.
| make: Leaving directory '/home/aksh/work/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs/lib/modules/5.15.108-yocto-standard'
```

Could you please help me to provide the correct path for `kernel_dir`, or provide other way to build the library?
In general, if I want to build up this library for any embedded device, how should I provide the path for `kernel_dir`?

I tried to find up the kernel_dir for the yocto image of the qemu, but was not able to find the correct one.

Comment: Try `${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}` variable. It supposed to be used to find the headers to build out of tree modules.